# Access to fetch blocked by CORS while getting data from swapi

Tags: javascript, fetch

Hi I try to get data from https://swapi.dev/api/ but i recive error in console: 'Access to fetch at 'https://swapi.dev/api/people' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.'

I'm doing this in that way:

```
  fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people',{
   headers: {
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'
   }
  })
  .then(res=>console.log(res))
```

I noticed, that on incognito everything is working fine

Comment: The header needs to be sent by the server, not the client.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about this error, what research have you done?

Comment: so how can I get data from this api?

Comment: Do it from your server, not the client.

Comment: Yes, and any helped me

Comment: there are MANY existing Stack Overflow questions regarding CORS issues with data fetching in Javascript.  which of them have you researched, what solutions have you attempted, and why did they not solve your specific problem?

Comment: I don't have server, it's public api

Comment: it didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the options you have and it should work

remove the

```
  {
   headers: {
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": '*'
   }
  }
```

What the server replies is that they do not allow this header in the request.

---

Additionally, if you want to log the actual data you need to first extract it from the response object

```
fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people')
  .then(response=>response.json())
  .then(data=>console.log(data))
```

Comment: no, it's not working

Comment: @robert do you still get the same error ?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: @robert is it the native browser `fetch` ? (*which browser and version and which os ?*)

Comment: Yes, now i notice, that on incognito everything is working